# A term for creating Internet traffic

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for the appropriate term or phrase (I think there is one ) that is used to refer to the practice of artificially increasing the Internet traffic on a subject, a product or an ad, for instance, (with more views, likes etc. ) to make them appear more attractive and more popular.

I am not familiar with Internet terminology so I can't do appropriate research on my own.

Comment: Artificially increasing? You mean by voting rings, fake accounts and that sort?

Comment: **click bait** is a cheap trick for getting more visitors. For example, using controversial titles, attractive thumbnails etc on YouTube videos..

Comment: Not necessarily fake accounts, but the intent is to make the subject look popular and attractive.

Comment: I don't think it's off topic, but more context would definitely improve the question.

Comment: I think it's called "Paying a bunch of Chinese to generate fake traffic."

Comment: on a tangent, I don't know the term, but someone who make such posts or artificial promotions for a private company is often called  a "corporate shill"

Comment: For one part, it's [search engine marketing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_marketing). Otherwise, it's "buzz marketing/creation/generation". See also [viral marketing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viral_marketing).

Comment: Spambot. Zombie. Botnet. Depends on the context.

Comment: to **drive, push or increase traffic** to a website. Those are the main verbs used to describe this activity.

Comment: In terms of getting spammed and hacked, there is something called Denial of Service (DOS) and Distributed Denial of Service (DDOS). Though this is related to hacking and computer geeky stuff.

Comment: If the action consists of posting bogus messages on various bulletin boards and the like, then that's "spam".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Click-bait** refers to internet content whose only merit is to generate traffic.  If I wanted to say a site has modified their content to degrade from it's quality for the sake of increasing traffic, I might say the site click-baited their content.

**Search engine optimization (SEO)** refers to the practice of making your site more likely to be returned by search engines.

**Astro-turfing** is used to describe a company or political group pretending to be a bottom up movement. A typical tactic is create false internet profiles and creating comments or reviews using an alias.

Perhaps one of these terms suits your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It is an umbrella term and can work in several scenarios.

Try [tout](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tout) - to solicit patronage

Comment: I think you are on the right track. Please elaborate.

Comment: @NVZ I don't think I possibly could because I've personally experienced it being used it when people promote a nightclub, store or some service. It is too broad.